# Cannot get HTML5 validation to work

Tags: angularjs, html, validation

I cannot get html5 validation to work when using it with AngularJS.

I simply need a field to be required, but instead of showing me the error, it submits the form.

I would appreciate anyone's input on how to get the html5 validation to work with AngularJS.

I have the following set up in my web.config file:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

I have the following set up in my masterpage:

```
<form id="userForm" name="userForm">
```

I have the following input box set up with the required attribute:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Check Slip Number" id="txtCDDepositSlipNumber" name="txtCDDepositSlipNumber" ng-model="formCtrl.depositSlip.selectedSlipID" required />

                    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post a more complete example? I made a fiddle, but I don't know if I'm doing it right, because I can't get the form to submit when there's nothing in the input...

Answer (score 0):

How do you submit form? You listen ng-submit (and have in the form of input type=submit) or handled ng-click on the button/item?

If the handle ng-submit the form - html5 validation works.

Answer (score 0):

```
write submit button like:

     <input type="submit" Value="Submit" ng-click="submitForm(model)">

ng-click will trigger the function you have written on angular controller.

by giving type="submit" to input tag validation would properly work on click of submit button.
```